# Mount .img created by ddrescue-gui

Tags: linux, linux-mint, mount, images, ddrescue

I'm trying to recover data after formatting my hdd. I installed ddrescue-gui and performed the following tasks:

1. Select source (formatted hdd), no log, destination (img file inside separate hdd) and set to fastest recovery then click start

[image]

2. Went into Computer and found that the source drive was now unmounted. So I went into Disks to see if I could mount it, but could not because it was now two loop devices:

[image]

3. So I tried various terminal commands to no avail, getting errors such as:

   sudo mount -t ntfs "/media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img" /dev/loop0

   NTFS signature is missing.
   Failed to mount '/dev/loop2': Invalid argument
   The device '/dev/loop2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
   Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
   partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
4. The file is currently sitting on a separate hdd and the 1tb hdd I'm trying to recover is inaccessible:

[image]

I'm new to this whole scene so I'm really confused at the moment. No idea why my drive got unmounted, converted to a "loop device" (whatever that is) and why I can't just get my data and then mount my device again. Is there a correct way of going about this?

I checked the official Launchpad GUI site but I didn't find any tutorials or guides or anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a image of a filesystem (`1tb.img`) inside a filesystem (`/dev/sdf` of `/media/user/e...aa5`).

try

```
sudo mount  "/media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img" /mnt
```

or

```
sudo mount -o loop "/media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img" /mnt
```

1. mount should find filesystem type.
2. add `-r` after mount to mount your image read only.

EDIT:

1. use `/mnt` (not `/media/user/XXYY`) as mount point.
2. `sudo mount -o ro,loop -t ntfs /media/user/e3../1tb.img /mnt`
3. try fstyp (or fstype) to check which filesystem

   ```
   fstype /media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img
   ```
4. analyse file using ... `file`

   ```
   file /media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img
   ```

Comment: both commands:

`sudo mount  "/media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img" "/media/user/B5C4-62C3"` or `sudo mount -o loop "/media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img" "/media/user/B5C4-62C3"`

result:

`mount: block device /media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem type`

with `-r`:

`mount: you must specify the filesystem type`

with `-t ntfs`:

`NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop2' doesn't seem to have a...`

Comment: @Hooli see my edit

Comment: for #1 and #2 I get the same errors mentioned above, for #3 I get `fstype: command not found`, for #4 I get `/media/user/e3cfeead-6e65-4af5-beb8-bbfa12fbdaa5/1tb.img: x86 boot sector`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use log with ddrescue.

Second, your image is going to be an image of whole drive which means you have to know where partitions starts.

```
+---------+-------...-+-------...-+-------...-+
| MBR PT  | part1     | part2     | partN     |
+---------+-------...-+-------...-+-------...-+
```

Use `file <image>` to gen information on your image. Should give you something more like: (that's my memory stick; you get the idea)

You can also use `fdisk <image>` or `cfdisk <image>`.
All they should show you geometry of your disk (in image) so you can find out where is beginning of partition to mount.

```
$ file sda.img
sda.img: MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xc, active, start-CHS (0x0,32,33), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 2048, 30308352 sectors
```

So proper mount line would be:

```
# mount -tvfat -oloop,offset=$((2048*512)) sda.img /mnt/sda1
```

as you have to inform `mount` where the actual partition starts - with `offset` option which is byte offset. That's why there is `offset=$(2048*512))` as `file/fdisk/cfdisk` shows it in sectors (although you can change units in `fdisk/cfdisk`).

Your commands will be more like

```
mkdir /mnt/image
sudo mount -o ro,loop,offset=YOUR_OFFSET -t ntfs /path/to/1tb.img /mnt/image
```